# x with a dot above instead of dx/dt when differentiating

Tags: python, sympy, symbols, derivative

Is there a way to change the expression for derivatives when using SymPy in Python?

```
from sympy import * 
x, t = symbols('x t')
expr_diff = Derivative(x, t)
```

In my code, `expr_diff` gives `dx/dt`. However, I would rather get the derivative of x with respect to t expressed as `ẋ` (x with a dot above).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to change it, but it requires to use the `sympy.physics.mechanics` package:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.mechanics import init_vprinting

# this is responsible to visualize time derivatives with dots
init_vprinting()

# then you need to define x as a functions of time
t = symbols("t")
x = Function("x")(t)

# Now you can visualize derivatives with dots
Derivative(x, t)
```